# Hadoop, handling a file with delimater but various length

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm a very beginner for hadoop. Just started with hive, impala of cdh5 on ubuntu 14.04.

My data's format is like

```
A¦aa¦bb¦cc
A¦bb¦cc¦ac¦dd¦ff¦fg
B¦aa¦ac
...
```

The first column could be a key, but other part doesn't have fixed length or fixed number of columns. All different. I have no idea how many columns are in each line. So I changed this to

```
Col1¦col2
A¦aa
A¦bb
A¦cc
A¦bb
A¦cc
A¦ac
A¦dd
....
```

But it takes so long since I have hundreds of files and each has more than 10M lines and 30GB size. And after I transformed the first format to the second, the file size was increased twice or three times. So I want to skip this process.

**Question 1.** 
If I import **the original file** into hdfs, can I use some sqls like this "select distinct col1, col2 from..." on hive or impala? Which will have a result

```
Col1¦col2
A¦aa
A¦bb
A¦cc
A¦ac
A¦dd
....
```

**Question 2.**
If Q1 is possible, what about the sql? Just the same thing? "select distinct col1, col2 from..."

Comment: ADD to Q1. I meant, is it possible without transformation? I want to upload the original file to hdfs and use the sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward and simple Mapreduce program would best fit your scenario , here is the code for your reference:

The below program will perform 2 operations at a time:

1) Collect row data and convert to key value pairs

2) Eliminate the duplicates and store only distinct values to output since the key is the combination of the initial token + value token, hence duplicates will be eliminated b reducer . example (A|bb) will be your key and null as value.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MRTranspose extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new MRTranspose(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = new Job(conf, this.getClass().toString());

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

        job.setJobName("transpose");
        job.setJarByClass(MRTranspose.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static class Map extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, NullWritable> {

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String words[] = line.split("¦");
            for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
                context.write(new Text(words[0] + "¦" + words[i]),
                        NullWritable.get());
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends
            Reducer<Text, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NullWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
        }
    }

}
```

provide raw data folder as first argument  and second argument as output folder

**Input file:** input.txt

```
 A¦aa¦bb¦cc
 A¦bb¦cc¦ac¦dd¦ff¦fg
 B¦aa¦ac
```

**Output file:**  part-r-00000 file

```
A¦aa
A¦ac
A¦bb
A¦cc
A¦dd
A¦ff
A¦fg
B¦aa
B¦ac
```

Finally, Bind your mapreduce output path as the input path for your hive tables for further querying

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**
Yes, It is possible to read your processed(after all your initial work) file through Hive or Impala. Solution I am providing you below is in Hive.

Login to Hive and create an external table.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Test_table(column1 string, column2 string)
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  STORED AS TEXTFILE
  LOCATION '/location/of/your/file/on/hdfs';
```

Based on the input provided in the question, i am assuming your delimiter to be '|' and the format to be text.This will create a table on top you data.

The same code can be used to create table in Impala.

**Question 2.**

Login to  Hive and run the below.

```
 select column1,column2 from test_table;
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but it seems to need the transformation first. When I created external table with the original file, it gave me wrong. A|aa (abandon the rest of the right) A|bb (abandon the rest of the right) B|aa ... I added more info to the post.